# NullPoiterException for java.util.ArrayList.size() on viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter)

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-viewpager

Some of our users (around 2%) are getting an error that I cannot reproduce on any physical and virtual device:

[image]

The line where this error corresponds is the last one of this piece of code:

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
fragments.add(Fragment1.newInstance(data1));
fragments.add(Fragment2.newInstance(data2));
fragments.add(Fragment3.newInstance(data3));
fragments.add(Fragment1.newInstance(data1));
fragments.add(Fragment2.newInstance(data2));
fragments.add(Fragment3.newInstance(data3));
CustomInfinitePagerAdapter mAdapter = new CustomInfinitePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter); //<-- Here is where our users have the crash
```

[image]

`mPager` is a `ViewPager`. I am replicating fragment 1 to 3 because the infinite view pager cannot have less than 4 fragment and I need to have 3. The `CustomInfinitePagerAdapter` is:

```
public class CustomInfinitePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> mFrags = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public CustomInfinitePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> frags) {
        super(fm);
        mFrags = frags;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (mFrags == null || mFrags.size() == 0)
            return null;
        while (position < 0)
            position += mFrags.size();

        int index = position % mFrags.size();
        return mFrags.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Samuel read my question. If I am posting this is because I need help. Not because I don't know what causes a NullPointerExeption. So please don't down vote my question.

Comment: Maybe try to add `CustomInfinitePagerAdapter mAdapter;` before `mAdapter = new CustomInfinitePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);`. I can't test it, because I am not currently on PC.

Comment: Please post stack trace of exception...

Comment: Samuel Tulach, of course that's done before. Samuel Arin question is updated. Thanks.

Comment: The exception states that a size() is being called on a null object. The line you are pointing out does not have a list. In the code the only possibility is that if fragments is null.

Comment: I know efekctive. That's why is so confusing and that's why I posted it here. I don't know why I am getting that error in that line. Maybe someone can help me.